Go AWS lambda, mock/ignore lambda.Start for coverage
I am testing with the following setup
func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, request LambdaRequest) (LambdaResponse, error) {

    return LambdaResponse{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Headers:    map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        Body:       "Hello World!",
    }, nil

}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}

I want to get code coverage to 100%
I am able to test the the actual handler, no problems. But I can't test main because you can't run that in a local environment. Code coverage drops but I want to make sure everything is covered.
How can I possibly mock this lambda start?

I think there is no way to mock lamda.Start. because it is a function. And AWS doesn't support a package like httptest. So I think the best is just to test HandlerRequestlike the samples https://github.com/aws-samples/lambda-go-samples/blob/master/main.go, https://github.com/aws-samples/lambda-go-samples/blob/master/main_test.go

When you want to have 100% test coverage, the best bet is to exclude the file containing main from your calculations.
The Google Testing Blog says that “at Google, 60% are acceptable, 75% commendable and 90% exemplary”. CodeCov writes that “we see that a significant portion of our open source repositories centers around 80% coverage”. JUnit reasons that “achieving 100% statement coverage is not realistic”. And what about your Branch coverage and MC/DC?
Tests should serve a purpose. If they are just performative you are hurting your program quality. Don't do it.
